# Ricci Tensor with Mathematica doesn't give the right answer

Tags: tensors

```
Clear[coord, metric, inversemetric, affine, riemann, ricci, scalar, \
t, r, θ, ϕ]
n = 2

coord = {θ, ϕ}

metric = {{r^2, 0}, {0, r^2*(sin[θ])^2}}

MatrixForm[metric]

inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]

MatrixForm[inversemetric]

affine := 
 affine = Simplify[
   Table[(1/2)*
     Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*(D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]]] + 
         D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - 
         D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1,
      n}, {k, 1, n}]]

listaffine := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
    0], {ToString[Γ[i, j, k]], affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 
   1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}]

TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

**Riemann Tensor**

Input:

```
riemann:=
riemann = Simplify[Table[
D[affin[[ i,j,l]],coord[[k]]]- 
D[affine[[ i,j,k]],coord[[l]]]+Sum[affine[[ s,j,l]]affine[[i,k,s]]- 
affine[[s,j,k]]affine[[i,l,s]],{s,1,n}],{i,1,n},{j,1,n},{k,1,n},{l,1,n}]]

listriemann:=Table[If[UnsameQ[riemann[[i,j,k,l]],0],{ToString[R[ 
i,j,k,l]],riemann[[i,j,k,l]]}],{i,1,n},{j,1,n},{k,1,n},{l,1,k - 1}]    

TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listriemann],Null],2],TableSpacing 
 ->{2,2}]
```

Output:

$$R[1, 2, 2, 1] = \text{sin}\ \theta\ \text{sin}'' \theta, \\
R[2, 1, 2, 1] = - \frac{\text{sin}''\theta}{\text{sin}\ \theta}$$

**Ricci Tensor**

Input:

```
ricci:= ricci =Simplify[Table[Sum[riemann[ [i,j,i,l]],{i,1,n}],{j,1,n}, 
{l,1,n}]]

listricci:=Table[If[UnsameQ[ ricci[[ j, l]], 0], {ToString[ 
R[j,l]],ricci[[j,l]]}],{j,1,n},{l, 1, j}]

TableForm[Partition [DeleteCases[ Flatten[ listricci], Null],2],TableSpacing 
-> {2, 2}]
```

Output:

$$R[1, 1] = - \frac{\text{sin}''\theta}{\text{sin}\ \theta} \\
R[2, 2] = \text{sin}'\theta^2$$

which shows that $R[2, 2] = \text{sin}'\theta^2$ is not the right answer. It should be $R[2, 2] = - \text{sin}\theta\ \text{sin}''\theta = (\text{sin}\ \theta)^2$ instead.

Why is that?

Comment: Your code does not execute. What's `n`? What's `affine`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  I just edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code: In the definition of `riemann`, you use `affin` which should occur in blue. That should tell you that this variable is not defined. You probably meant to write `affine`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you!!!